# gnuplot ignores second branch in multi-branch fitting

Tags: function, branch, gnuplot, curve

I want to do a multi-branch fit with gnuplot. I defined two functions z1(x) and z2(x) and I want that z1(x) is fitted with all data up to line 49 and starting from line 50 it should fit to z2(x). This is what I do in the fitting part:

```
z(x,y) = (y < 50) ? z1(x) : z2(x)

fit z(x,y) 'data.txt' using  1:-1:2  via a, b
```

But gnuplot completly ignores the z2(x) part. I can even comment out the defintion of z2(x), it gives not even an error nor a warning. It never reaches the case where y >= 50, but the data.txt file has 100 lines.

Also, if I plot z1(x) and z2(x) afterwards, they are just constant zero (z1 = z2 = 0), but the fit parameters a and b are roughly (not fully, because 2nd branch is ignored) in the right order.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a good example somehwere (the official gnuplot fit demo didn't help)?

Comment: I think you probably want `using 1:($0):2`, but I'm not completely sure (pseudo-column `0` should be the line number.  `help datafile using pseudo-column` (although, a quick look there makes me think that maybe -1 would be Ok)...

Comment: I tried that but it did not change anything...

Comment: 'd suggest first eliminate the fit and manually specify a=,b= and see if you get the sort of plot you expect.  Its hard to see what going on without knowing what your functions are..  (presumably a and b appear in both? )

Comment: yes, a and b appear in both. The functions are of type z1(x) = (a+b)x + z10 and z2(x) = (a-b)x + z20

Comment: From the v4 manual: To fit a function with two independent variables, z=f(x,y), the required format is using with four items,
x:y:z:s. The complete format must be given — no default columns are assumed for a missing token.
Weights for each data point are evaluated from ’s’ as above. If error estimates are not available, a
constant value can be specified as a constant expression (see plot datafile using (p. 43)), e.g., using
1:2:3:(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that your line number in the 'data.txt' file is the `x` variable for your function `z(x)`, you can make it simpler (this is necessary for this to work, actually!!!). Your function `z(x,y)` is in reality just single variable function `z(x)` defined separately on two intervals. I re-created your problem with a sample data file, where the ranges for `z1(x)` and `z2(x)` break at the 10th point of my data file (you want 49 or 50 there).

The following code does what you want; defines the function `z(x)` differently for the first 10 data points and the rest (this is where the `x` HAS to be equal to line number),

```
z1(x) = a*x + b
a = 1.2
b = 1.2
z2(x) = a + b
z(x) = x < 10 ? z1(x) : z2(x)
```

then fit the data file using the data point line number (`column(0)`) as x and the value on the respective line (`1`) as y, varying parameters `a` and `b`

```
 fit z(x) 'data.txt' using (column(0)):1 via a,b
```

and plot to see how we do

```
 plot 'data.txt' using (column(0)):1, z(x)
```

If this doesn't work, you may look into the `index` option for plotting data files. This would require separating the data ranges (first 50 points) in your data file by one blank line (or two, can't remember) and modify the script accordingly.